# Textarea width does not work, but offset does

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

This is my code (see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EK64U/)):

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='offset1 span5'>
            <textarea rows='3'></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='offset1 span1'>
            <textarea rows='3'></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect both `textarea`s to have different width, but they have the same width. How can I control both the `offset` and `span` features of Bootstrap for `textarea`s?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/EK64U/2/

Comment: Note: I think `cols` is a required attribute even if it is overridden by a css width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do it -Jsfiddle for you [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/EK64U/4/)

Method 1: Uses of block level classes, Like

```
<textarea class="input-xxlarge" rows='3'></textarea>
<textarea class="input-large" rows='3'></textarea>
<textarea class="input-mini" rows='3'></textarea>
```

Method 2 :Grid Level resizing , Like

```
<textarea class="span12" rows='3'></textarea>
<textarea class="span6" rows='3'></textarea>
```

You can specify any span size according to your liking .

For your code you can use :

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='offset1 span5'>
        <textarea class="input-large" rows='3'></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
    <div class='offset1 span1'>
        <textarea class="input-mini" rows='3'></textarea>

    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```